# How to apply required validation on mat-chip in template driven form?

Tags: angular, validation, angular-material

I have a form which includes a mat-chip and a button in form (template-driven) and I want to disable submit button if mat-chip is not validated,

demo.component.html

```
<form #demoForm="ngForm">
    <mat-form-field >
        <mat-chip-list #chipList>
            <mat-chip *ngFor="let item of list" [selectable]="true"
                          (remove)="remove(item)" required" #chips="ngModel" name="chips">
                  {{item}}
                  <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
            </mat-chip>
                <input placeholder="enter item"
                       [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
                       [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
                       [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="true"
                       (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)"/>
        </mat-chip-list>
    </mat-form-field>    
    <button mat-button type="submit" [disabled]="demoForm.invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In demo.component.ts, I have defined functions to add and delete chips in my input

```
class Demo{

  public separatorKeysCodes = [ENTER, COMMA];
  public list = [];
    add(event): void {
        if (event.value) {
          this.list.push(event.value);
        }
        if (event.input) {
          event.input.value = '';
        }
      }


    remove(data: any): void {
        if (this.list.indexOf(data) >= 0) {
          this.list.splice(this.list.indexOf(data), 1);
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: You are mixing a bit, the template driven and reactive, first only set as <mat-chip ..... required> instead of [required] = true, it's not needed the input attribute, and second, your <button> needs to be a type="submit" button

Comment: I updated my code as you said @Kalamarico , but then I got this error at run time

Error: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel"

Comment: It's due to this: '#chips="ngModel"' It's not allowed, I don't know what you are trying to do with that, but #__name__ it's an identifier not works with ngModel

Comment: If you make a stackblitz with your code I can try to help you

Comment: @Kalamarico stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-chip-demo.
Now, it has console error. I need to show error message and disable button if no value is entered in mat-chip

Comment: First you must do a thing, your console error is due to you are using in the template the variable "chips" and it's not exist, I thing you mean demoForm, this is your form variable, and you need to change all "chips" by "demoForm", after that you will fix the console error, and check again

Comment: ok If I remove "chips" template variable from html, then can you tell me how can I apply required validation? Code updated: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-chip-demo

Comment: It's very easy, set the required inside mat-chip-list instead of mat-chip, like this: <mat-chip-list #chipList required>and remove the mat-chip required

Comment: How I will get to know whether chip-list is valid or not? As I want to display error message if user doesnot enter any value in chip-list

Comment: I think you need to use the Reactive forms way (instead of template-driven way), you need read more about it, take a look to this post: https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-custom-validator/

Comment: I have already tried it with reactive forms and it is working but I want to know is it possible with template-driven form or not